# How to fetch the value of token from url and assign it to value of input

Tags: angular

Currently it doesn't take the value of token input token it just prints '' in the console as I have defined token as 
token: [''] in the form builder. How should I define it so that it taken the correct value.
The whole point of this is eventually to fetch the value of token from mydomain.com/reset-password?token=2724a63c5ab6866ae385ea211cb1
so 2724a63c5ab6866ae385ea211cb1 in this case should be updated in the hidden token input field so it could be sent on form submission to the backend.

html (I am using reactive form here)

```
<form [formGroup]="resetPassword" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div id="tab-1" class="log-tab-content current">
      <div class="login-form">
        <div class="login-left">
            <input type="text" formControlName="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter New Password *"/>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="login-right">
          <input type="text" formControlName="c_password" placeholder="Confirm Password *"/>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" formControlName="token" name="token" value="2724a63c5ab6866ae385ea211cb1d3812696fe574a71817515e50038a0881aa1">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <button type="submit" class="log-button log-button1">Reset Password</button>
      </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Typescript

```
 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetPassword = this.formBuilder.group({
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      c_password: ['', Validators.required],
      token: ['']
    })
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.resetPassword.invalid) {
      return;
  }
  const user = {
    password: this.resetPassword.controls.password.value,
    c_password: this.resetPassword.controls.c_password.value,
    token: this.resetPassword.controls.token.value
  };

  console.log(user);

  this.auth.resetPasswordToken(user).subscribe( (res: any) => {
    if(res) {
     console.log(res);
    }
  },(err)=> {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  });
}
```

Comment: HI, Is your issue resolved?

Comment: I found a better way to do this in angular and it doesn't require separate input and it fetches the value of token from the url  `route.queryParams.subscribe(params=>{
      this.form.token = params['token']
    });`

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED:

Bind an ngModel to your input `[(ngModel)]="mytoken"` like below.

```
<input type="hidden" formControlName="token" name="token" [(ngModel)]="mytoken" value="2724a63c5ab6866ae385ea211cb1d3812696fe574a71817515e50038a0881aa1">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <button type="submit" class="log-button log-button1">Reset Password</button>
        </div>
```

And in  your ts, initialize a variable `mytoken` and after your subscribe, add the following

```
  this.auth.resetPasswordToken(user).subscribe( (res: any) => {
    if(res) {
     console.log(res);
     this.mytoken = res; // depends on the response data. It could also be res.token
    }
  },(err)=> {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  });
```

If you cannot use `ngModel` on `input` field based on the version of angular, you can use `setValue`

```
  this.auth.resetPasswordToken(user).subscribe( (res: any) => {
    if(res) {
     console.log(res);
     this.resetPassword.controls['token'].setValue(res); // depends on the response data. It could also be res.token
    }
  },(err)=> {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  });
```

Comment: You can not use ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. 
    Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with 
    reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
    in Angular v7.

Comment: @AniketAvhad, I was aware of it but he did not mention the version he is using. So, I gave an idea of what could be done.